# Rendering table in bllim datatables Laravel 4

Tags: laravel-4

I don't know how to render datatable  in view, here is the code in my controller.

```
public function getTable()
{


           $tasks = Todo::select(array('todos.id','todos.task','todos.deadline','todos.status'));

            return Datatables::of($tasks)->make();


}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You need to create the datatable structure in your view and call the controller method with jQuery.

For example in your view you can set the following html:

```
<table id="tasks" class="table table-striped table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="col-md-3">ID</th>
            <th class="col-md-3">Task</th>
            <th class="col-md-3">Deadline</th>
            <th class="col-md-3">Status</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

And then add the following jQuery that calls your controller action

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var oTable;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        oTable = $('#tasks').dataTable( {
            "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
            "bProcessing": true,
            "bServerSide": true,
            "sAjaxSource": "{{ URL::to('tasks/getTable') }}"
        });
    });
</script>
```

You also need to reference the following files in your page

http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js
and
http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.0/js/jquery.dataTables.js

and also add the Controller/getTable method to your routes file (in the example above I wrote it as tasks/getTable

Answer (score 0):

If you need features like filters, sorting, etc., try [Nayjest/Grids](https://github.com/Nayjest/Grids) package for Laravel. If you need just simple table -- previous response is preferred.